What are the cohomology groups $H^n(k, \mathbb{Q/Z})$ for a field $k$?
I'm reading a source that connects Brauer groups of fields $k$ to $H^1(k, \mathbb{Q/Z})$,
but the source doesn't define the cohomology groups $H^\bullet(k, \mathbb{Q/Z})$.
Googling the definition proves unsuccessful as well, so I'm asking here.

A standard reference is Cassels-Frohlich, "Algebraic Number Theory", Chapter 4 and 5.

We usually write $H^*(k, M)$ to mean the group cohomology of $G_k$ acting on $M$, where $G_k$ is the Galois group of a choice of algebraic closure of $k$ over $k$. When you write $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ like that, it probably means with the trivial action, so this $H^1$ is just a Hom.

the thing to google is "galois cohomology" or "group cohomology" if you haven't seen any of this before, by the way !

This is great! Thank you so much @hunter
